# Derive spherical coordinates in a left handed system from cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

How do I derive to spherical coordinates in left handed cartesian coordinate system. And vice versa, how do you get cartesian coordinates from φ and θ in spherical coordinate system in left handed system.

Thanks!

Comment: Same way as in the right-handed system, I'd imagine: basic trigonometry.

Comment: Would you be willing to derive it?